# how to check that contact is already added to iphone phonebook or not?

Tags: iphone

I want to check the iphone phonebook that whether a contact is already added or not, if added then I won't add it, it is not added then I will add new contact,,,,
I want just want to compare a name such as "Veer" exists in phonebook or not

Answer (score 3):

```
ABAddressBookRef addressbook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(Nil, Nil);
 NSArray *people = (__bridge NSArray*)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressbook);
NSMutableArray *namearray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(id person in people){
      NSString *firstNameString = (__bridge NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue((__bridge   ABRecordRef)(person),kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    NSLog(@"%@",firstNameString);
        [namearray addObject:firstNameString];
  }
    NSLog(@"%@",namearray);
NSString *yourString = name you want to add;
BOOL identicalStringFound = NO;
for (NSString *someString in namearray) {
    if ([someString isEqual:yourString]) {
        identicalStringFound = YES;
        break;
    }
}
if(identicalStringFound)
 {
    //code you want to perform
 }
else
 {
    //code you want to perform
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
+ (NSArray *) findContactsContainingName: (NSString *) fname
{
    // Load the contacts
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = CFAutorelease(ABAddressBookCreate());
    NSArray *thePeople = (NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
    NSMutableArray *contacts = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:thePeople.count];
    for (id person in thePeople)
        [array addObject:[ABContact contactWithRecord:(ABRecordRef)person]];
    [thePeople release];

    // search the contacts for fname
    NSPredicate *pred;
    pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstname contains[cd] %@ OR lastname contains[cd] %@ OR nickname contains[cd] %@ OR middlename contains[cd] %@", fname, fname, fname, fname];
    return [contacts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
}
```

Comment: ABAddressBookRef showing error in Xcode 7.3.. Anything to import?